# How to update a collection using Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a one to many relationship between `Device` and `Command` models (each `Device` has many `commands`). Now I want to update a collection of commands using `save()` method. So, I used the following code:

```
$device = Device::find(1);
$commands = $device->commands()->whereStatus("pending")->get();

$commands->status = "sent";
$commands->save();
```

But I got a `FatalErrorException` exception with an error message of `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save()`.

In other words, I am looking for an equivalent MySQL query of the following in the `Eloquent`:

```
UPDATE commands SET status = 'sent' WHERE status = 'pending';
```

using Laravel 4.2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could try the `update` method on the `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` object:

```
$queryBuilder = $device->commands()->whereStatus("pending");
$queryBuilder->update(array("status" => "sent"));
```

Comment: And how could I get the collection after updating?

Comment: Assign that line to a variable -- should do it.

Comment: Oh yeah. Separate to two lines? Sec, updating.

Comment: Thanks, I edited your answer. I have to get data before updating `status` because after that I'll get an empty collection.

Comment: @user1922137, to get the result, simply return the model after saving.
`return response()->json($service);`

Comment: Does anyone know why `->save();` doesn't work in this case? Happened to me too and `->update()` worked... but why? `->save();` didn't throw an error.

Comment: I have just a comment to this: the variable `$collection` is not actually a collection, is an instance of query builder class, the update() method does not belong to the Collection class.

Comment: This shouldn't really be an accepted answer - it "works", per comment above, due to `$collection` being instance of QueryBuilder

Comment: The question is "How to update a collection", if you don't use get or first, this is not a collection. Wrong answer.

Comment: Bad answer, we want to know how or if it is possible, save/update from a collection.

Answer (score 8):

Since `$commands` is a collection, changing the value of `$commands->status` will not have the effect that you intend (setting the value of `status` to 'sent' for every item in the collection).

Instead, act on each item in the collection independently:

```
foreach ($commands as $command)
{
    $command->status = 'sent';
    $command->save();
}
```

You can also update the items in the database via Query Builder:

```
DB::table('your_table')->where('status', 'pending')->update(array('status' => 'pending'));
```

Comment: Or combine to `[your class]::whereIn('id', $collection->pluck('id'))->update($data)`. In this example it will be `Device::whereIn('id', $commands->pluck('id'))->update(['status' => 'pending'])`

Comment: This is why I love doctrine, and I hate eloquent.

Comment: Its always best to try to avoid any database interactions in loops to minimise your Big O number.

Answer (score 6):

New feature updates for [laravel 7+](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections#method-toquery) :

```php
  $device = Device::find(1);
  $commands = $device->commands()->whereStatus("pending")->get();
  $commands->toQuery()->update(array("status" => "sent"));

  // you can reload fresh data
  $commands->fresh();
```

Comment: `toQuery()` is what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I know it solve the problem but answering for new users that how they can update the laravel model collection

Simply add an update on the collection

```
Mail::where('to', auth()->user()->email)->update([
    'is_seen' => 1
]);
```