# Eloquent - Updating all models in a collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to set a certain attribute in all the models of a collection.

in plain SQL:

```
UPDATE table SET att = 'foo' WHERE id in (1,2,3)
```

the code i have:

```
$models = MyModel::findMany([1,2,3]);
$models->update(['att'=>'foo']);
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597266/how-to-update-a-collection-using-eloquent-laravel)

but doesn't work. I'm getting

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update()
```

the only way i have found it's building a query with the query builder but i'd rather avoid that.

Comment: Eloquent is a query builder, not an ORM. It does not define `update` on model instances. You can define it yourself, but in the end somewhere in _your_ code you have to write `MyModel::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->update(...)`.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Actually Eloquent is an ORM

Comment: Just googled the same question. Hai~

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You are returning a collection, not keeping the query open to update. Like your example is doing.

```
$models = MyModel::whereIn('id',[1,2,3]);
$models->update(['att'=>'foo']);
```

`whereIn` will query a column in your case `id`, the second parameter is an array of the ids you want to return, but will not execute the query. The `findMany` you were using was executing it thus returning a Collection of models.

If you need to get the model to use for something else you can do `$collection = $models->get();` and it will return a collection of the models.

If you do not just simply write it on one line like so;

```
MyModel::whereIn('id',[1,2,3])->update(['att'=>'foo']);
```

Another option which i do not recommend is using the following;

```
$models = MyModel::findMany([1,2,3]);

$models->each(function ($item){
    $item->update(['att'=>'foo']);
});
```

This will loop over all the items in the collection and update them individually. But I recommend the `whereIn` method.

Comment: the `whereIn` method worked. but what if i have a model collection. there's no way to update all of them at once?

Comment: No there is not without going through them each i added that as an option at the end of the answer, but i do not recommend this.

Comment: no, i dont recommend it either, that's why i was looking for an alternative

Comment: A new Collection method called `toQuery()` was added that will help when you already have the collection, to avoid having to loop through them all.  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-toquery

Comment: Be careful that with this method being batch updates, model callbacks like `::updating` and `::updated` won't be fired.

Answer (score 16):

The best solution in one single query is still:

```
MyModel::whereIn('id',[1,2,3])->update(['att'=>'foo']);
```

If you already have a collection of models and you want to do a direct update you can use `modelKeys()` method. Consider that after making this update your `$models` collection remains outdated and you may need to refresh it:

```
MyModel::whereIn('id', $models->modelKeys())->update(['att'=>'foo']);
$models = MyModel::findMany($models->modelKeys());
```

The next example I will not recommend because for every item of your `$models` collection a new extra query is performed:

```
$models->each(function ($item) {
    $item->update(['att'=>'foo']);
});
```

or simpler, from [Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#higher-order-messages) you can do `$models->each->update(['att'=>'foo']);`

However, the last example (and only the last) is good when you want to trigger some model events like `saving`, `saved`, `updating`, `updated`. Other presented solutions are touching direct the database but models are not waked up.

Comment: does this `update`need to be in a `DB::transaction` block?

Comment: @TusharKoul it's your requirements that must answer that question. If you're fine with some updates going through if one fails, then no. Otherwise, yes

Answer (score 4):

Just use the following:

```
MyModel::query()->update([
    "att" => "foo"
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Be mindful that batch updating models won't fire callback `updating` and `updated` events. If you need those to be fired, you have to execute each update separately, for example like so (assuming `$models` is a collection of models):

```php
$models->each(fn($model) => $model->update(['att'=>'foo']) );
```