# Laravel: update rows with one query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `title` and `slug` field in my table, where `slug` == `null`. And now how I can write to `slug` field `title` slug using facade `Str::slug($title)` with one query if it possible of course.

I can do it looping with many queries to database:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $post->update(['slug' => Str::slug($post->title)]);
}
```

But how I can do it something like this with one query:

```
Post::all()->update(['slug' => Str::slug($this->title)]);
```

Maybe it's possible by adding `callback` to collection `all()` method?

Comment: It won't work with `all()`, but you can use `whereIn`
See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44200724/7056539

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this as long as the value for all of them is the same.

```
Post::query()->update(['slug' => Str::slug($this->title)]);
```

You can check it with

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
Post::query()->update(['slug' => Str::slug($this->title)]);
$log = DB::getQueryLog();
dd($log);
```

Comment: Missing a [ but this should work. Correct syntax: `Post::query()->update(['slug' => Str::slug($this->title)]);`

Comment: @BramVerstraten Good catch. When I copied over his code I must have deleted the first [. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to do it is not possible because the method `all()`
returns a collection and there is no such method update associated with that.

Though you can create a method in the controller to execute the foreach that you mentioned and turn your code more clean.