# Stuck at Error = Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist

Tags: laravel

Trying to save data while open page but stuck at error :

> "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist."

I have 2 database :

1. `Buffalodata`
2. `Buffalomilkrecord`

From 2nd table i need to get the avg of `totalmilk` and update the same to main database (1). This help me to show updated `avgmilk` data on dashboard front page.

Route:

```
 Route:: get('buffalo-details', 'App\Http\Controllers\BuffalodataController@buffalodetails');
```

BuffalodataController Controller :

```
  public function buffalodetails()
      {
      
       $buffalidforavgmilk     = Buffalodata::groupBy('buffaloID')->get('buffaloID')->pluck('buffaloID')->toArray();
        
      foreach ($buffalidforavgmilk as $id ) 
        {
          $milkperid  =  Buffalomilkrecord::where('buffaloID', $id)->sum('totalmilk');
          $avgbuffalocount = Buffalomilkrecord::where('buffaloID',$id)->count();
          $getavg =   $milkperid / $avgbuffalocount;

               $data = Buffalodata::find($buffalidforavgmilk);

               $data->avgmilk   = ($getavg);

               $data->save ();
                                
                                
          // dump([$milkperid,$avgbuffalocount,$getavg,$data,$id]);
                                
           }

       return view ('pages.Buffalo.BuffaloDetails',[---------]);

      }
```

Thanks again in Advance

Comment: you pass the array to the find method: `$data = Buffalodata::find($buffalidforavgmilk);` should be `$data = Buffalodata::find($id);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a collection using Eloquent Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597266/how-to-update-a-collection-using-eloquent-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an Array to `::find()`, it returns a `Collection`, which doesn't have a `save()` method. This is your code:

```php
// This is an Array of `buffaloID` values
$buffalidforavgmilk = Buffalodata::groupBy('buffaloID')->get('buffaloID')->pluck('buffaloID')->toArray();
...
// `$data` is now a `Collection` of `Buffalodata` instances
$data = Buffalodata::find($buffalidforavgmilk);
// This now fails, as `Collection` doesn't have a `save()` method
$data->save();
```

You can rewrite your code as follows:

```php
Buffalodata::whereIn('buffaloID', $buffalidforavgmilk)->update(['avgmilk' => $getavg]);
```

This will update all records in a single call. If you want to iterate, that's an option too:

```php
$data = Buffalodata::find($buffalidforavgmilk);
foreach ($data as $record) {
  $record->avgmilk = $getavg;
  $record->save();
}
```

Or, since you have `$id` already:

```php
$record = Buffalodata::find($id);
$record->avgmilk = $getavg;
$record->save();
```

Comment: "Buffalodata::where('buffaloID', $buffalidforavgmilk)->update(['avgmilk' => $getavg]);" this code only update the data for first id....balance id are not getting updated

Comment: Ah sorry, that should be `whereIn()`; let me fix.

Comment: Yes .... but again 1 prob.  avgmilk of first id is showing for all balance ID. Thanks i m new learner

Comment: Yeah, it would. If that update all line doesn't work for your needs (it was a little unclear from your code), please look at the rest of my answer; it provides examples on how to iterate and update one-by-one.

Comment: Sure... Spoon feeding is good for a learner... Thanks again....

Comment: You're welcome? I can't tell if that comment is sincere or not   Basically, if the `->update()` call isn't what you need, all you need to change in your original code is `$data = Buffalodata::find($id);` instead of `$data = Buffalodata::find($buffalidforavgmilk);`, which is why I didn't include the code for `$getavg` in my answer at all; that code is fine as-is (could be improved, but it works just fine)

Comment: Finally got Working.... Code  = Buffalodata::whereIn('buffaloID', [$id])->update(['avgmilk' => $getavg]);

Comment: Close! `Buffalodata::where('buffaloID', $id)->update(['avgmilk' => $getavg]);`. You don't need to use `whereIn()` and cast `$id` to an array via `[$id]` if you only have a single value `$id` 